# Why don't <textarea> and <input> elements respect max-width?

Tags: html, css

The following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
span,textarea,div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
}
</style>
<div></div><br>
<textarea></textarea><br>
<input type=text><br>
```

Renders the following in Chrome and FF.

[image]

Why isn't the `<textarea>` and the `<input>` as wide as the `<div>`?

Comment: It's because `div` is a natural block element and the other two are natural inline elements. You need to give them all the same `min-width` and `width` too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most browsers respect `max-width`, but `INPUT` and `TEXTAREA` elements typically have a width set by default in the user agent CSS. You can add this CSS for a consistent rendering:

```
input,textarea{width:100%;display:block}
```

Comment: If he just put width and add input doesn't work ?

span,textarea,div,input {
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    width:300px;
}

Comment: @ShadowWizard The `display: block` would render the need for breaks unnecessary.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: the jsfiddle doesn't demonstrate working `max-width` for the `textarea` or `input` elements: they don't get narrower as the screen width is reduced.

Comment: "INPUT and TEXTAREA elements typically have a width set by default in the user agent CSS." Not really. If they had fixed width values in the user agent stylesheet they would be too easily overridable by applying `width:auto`. In fact, being replaced elements, their used widths come from another layer,  their `intrinsic width`s.

Answer (score 7):

Ran into this very problem this morning. While the first answer relates to mine, I feel further explanation is necessary:

Working Demo: **[jsFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/collarbone/raxsj7vn/2/)**

1) As stated above, first it's important to set inputs to 100% width at the top of your css file:

```
input,textarea {
     width:100%;
     display:block }
```

2) The input will now, by default, extent 100% of the length of the parent div. So if you want to achieve a "max-width," you need to set width properties within the parent div.

```
.input-container {
     max-width: 300px; }
```

3) Add padding to the parent div to give a fixed space to the right/left of the input

```
.input-container {
     padding: 25px 25px;
     max-width: 300px; }
```

Let me know if something isn't clear.

**[jsFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/collarbone/raxsj7vn/2/)**

Comment: Well explained answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

A div - like any other block-element - generally takes 100% of the available width. Because you limited the width (with max-width) to 200px, the div will have 200px. `<textarea>` and `<input>` are inline elements. They still have a width, because every element has a default width.

To solve your problem: if you want the `<textarea>`and `<input>` fields to be as wide as your div, you'll have to change the `width`-attribute, not the `max-width` one.
Leaving out the "max" will make them all equally wide.

Comment: Using `width` does not achieve my objective - I want the `input` and the `textarea` elements to get narrower as the screen width gets narrower.

Comment: @HorseloverFat You need to edit your original question to include that information.

Comment: @Ally I would say it's fairly obvious that I want the behaviour of `max-width` because the question is about... `max-width` and `max-width` is even in the title.

Comment: @HorseloverFat No, you need to clarify in your question that you want the "elements to get narrower as the screen width gets narrower" because there is no way of knowing that given your question.

Comment: No, I don't. It's obvious. The fact that I'm asking about `max-width` makes it obvious that I want "elements to get narrower as the screen width gets narrower" because that is the behaviour of `max-width`.

Comment: @Ally If I wanted to know how to set the `width` of the element (as per this answer) I would have asked: `Why don't <textarea> and <input> elements respect width?`

Comment: @HorseloverFat max-width can apply to many scenarios that have no relation whatsoever to window width. Example: an element with a max-width contained by an element that is off-screen by positioning or horizontal scroll.