# Input does not respect max-width

Tags: html, css, input, html-table, width

I know my question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175211/why-dont-textarea-and-input-elements-respect-max-width), but my situation is slightly different and also there is no solution in the other question.

So, I have the following markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>I respect max-width</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input value="I do not" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With the following styles:

```
table {
    width: 200px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
td {
    width: 50%;
    background: #e7e7e7;
}
div, input {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

This would be the expected result:

[image]

But, this is the actual one:

[image]

Somehow the `auto` width of the input field determined by the browser is larger than 50% (100px). That's all fine and dandy, but why isn't it respecting the `max-width: 100%`?

If I force set `width: 100%` it works as expected (second image), however that's not what I want. I want it to be as wide as the browser decides is good, just not wider than 100%.

Any ideas?

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s25w8ace/).

Comment: Have you check your fiddle shows different result in chrome and firefox?

Comment: It shows the same result at least for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could help you: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s25w8ace/1/)

```
td {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    background: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the table to `table-layout: fixed` you get the result you want:

```
table {
    width: 200px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

input {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Nice, that works great, but I'll accept @fcastillo 's answer, just because he was first, I hope you don't mind :)