# Why <input/> takes so much initial space, and how to control it?

Tags: html, css

Let me explain:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.line {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.square {
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
input {
  flex: 1;
}
.inputs {
  background-color: yellow
}
.inputs.none {
  display: none;
}

.reduce-font-size input {
  font-size: 4px;
}
```

```html
Inputs display none
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row inputs none">
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>

Inputs visible
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row inputs">
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>

Inputs reduced font-size

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row inputs reduce-font-size">
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the purpose of this to make the container flexible and resizable without knowing anything about the parameters. We set up initial parameters for the square, and everything must follow those values, then on resize the container's content should stretch. The only problem is with the inputs. We can't set specified width for them, they should fill the maximum available width, but by not expanding their row. The example with reduced font-size works well. It doesn't expand the row, but if the container's width changing, they follow it, but... the font-size will be too small then. What I want is the same behaviour with normal font-size. So there should be something with the font-properties, but after a few hours of playaround, I get some help from you. Any ideas?

Comment: `width: 0;` to input ?

Comment: Literally tried everything except this...

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

```
input {
  width:100%;
}
.inputs {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

By then you only need to control the container to set the width. Related: [Why don't <textarea> and <input> elements respect max-width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175211/why-dont-textarea-and-input-elements-respect-max-width)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.line {
  width: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.square {
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
input {
  flex: 1;
  width:100%;
}
.inputs {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.inputs.none {
  display: none;
}

.reduce-font-size input {
  font-size: 4px;
}
```

```html
Inputs display none
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row inputs none">
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>

Inputs visible
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row inputs">
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>

Inputs reduced font-size

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row inputs reduce-font-size">
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
  </div>
</div>
```